# Reload react-table on event

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-table

I'm using React as a display tool for my data, coupled with the [framework react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) to list my data.

I have a field to create a new object in my data base but I can't reload the table without leaving my view.

My question, how to reuse the function to load the data? ([source code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#server-side-data))

```
class ElementCRDN extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleCreation = this.handleCreation.bind(this);
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            data: [], // the data retrieved from the server
            pages: -1,
       };
   }

   handleCreation(event) {
        Axios.post('/createElement', {
            // data
        }).then(() => {
            // Ask for reload
       });
       event.preventDefault();
   }

   render() {
       <form onSubmit={this.handleCreation}>
           // input to create object
       </form>
       <ReactTable
          data={this.state.data}
          pages={this.state.pages}
          loading={this.state.loading}
          manual
          columns={columns}
          onFetchData={(state) => { // function to retrieve the data
              this.setState({ loading: true });
              Axios.post('/listElements', {
                  page: state.page,
                  pageSize: state.pageSize,
                  sorted: state.sorted,
                  filtered: state.filtered,
              }).then((res) => {
                  this.setState({
                  data: res.data,
                  loading: false,
                  });
              });
          }}
       />
   }
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: I posted an [issue](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/955) on the git too, I was missing a key feature of React: it does not rerender child component if their state does not change.

@Explosion Pills was right, I needed to understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply add the element to your data upon successful creation. You can use `this.setState` again with the new data value you were posting with `createElement`.

```
async handleCreation(event) {
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  await Axios.post('/createElement', data);
  this.setState({ data: this.state.data.concat(data), loading: false });
}
```

Comment: This would work in most cases, but for me, the backend alter the data which prevent me from simply insert the sent data in the array.